# HotTowel modal dialog

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

Recently, I started my first visual studio knockout/breeze app using one of the templates found online, and I wanted a modal dialog to open similar to this:

```
 <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

 <div id="openModal " class="modalDialog">
           <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
           <div data-bind="foreach: userDetails">                   
               <p>User details go here</p>
               <p data-bind="text: $data.name" />
               <p data-bind="text: $data.role" />                        
           </div>                   
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#FFFFFF;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
border:2px solid #4cff00;
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events:stroke;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border:1px solid;
border-color: #fee209;
border-radius: 1px;
background: #b5a526;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#b5a526, #000);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b5a526, #000);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#b5a526, #000);
}

.close {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #204510;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

This worked fine, but now I'm attempting to implement this into a knockout/breeze application with hotTowel.  Now when I click on the link button, I get a warning of 'No Route Found', and no pop-up.  I gather hotTowel thinks I'm trying to navigate somewhere, is there a way to tell it not to in this instance?  Or is it because hotTowel uses html instead of cshtml for the views?  Can I not do it this way with hotTowel?

Comment: I think the "No Route Found" message is because your link has `href="#openModal"`, so it is routing your browser to #openModal.  What is setting up your event handler for that link?  What javascript is supposed to run when that link is clicked?

Comment: None as far as I know.  It just worked using css alone, when the openModal div is targeted the opacity it set to 1 in css.

Comment: error occurred because you defined route `#openModal`. You can fix it by replacing the `<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>` to `<button data-bind="click: doSomething">ButtonName</button>`.

Comment: Secondly if you really wanna navigate somewhere, you have to define the route in `shell.js` like in your case `{ route: 'openModal', moduleId: 'openModal', name: 'Modal', nav: 0 }` add this to your route then your `<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it thinks you are trying to navigate, what did you expect from

```
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
```

if not navigation? That's what anchor tags *do* when they have an `href` attribute. You're getting a route exception instead of a 404 because the navigation is intercepted by the router and `#close` doesn't match any of the routes you have defined, but that doesn't change the underpinning problem.

If you want a click handler then you should define a click handler instead of a navigation anchor.

Write a JS function in scope. The most sensible place for this is as a method of your view-model, since validation requires access to any collected data which I *hope* you are binding to the view-model.

Then bind it. You can keep the anchor tag if it's important to your styling, but replace the `href` attribute with `data-bind="click: yourVM.theMethod"`

Or (assuming you put a method on the VM) you can use a binding reference like `$root.theMethod`. You could also use a relative reference and if you don't know what that is, I strongly encourage you to [do the tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: I guess I expected it to work like it had been working.

Comment: Fair enough. I always find it puzzling when examples use anchor tags for anything other than hyperlinks. It implies things that are not true.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using durandal's dialog.show and a new viewmodel/view opened from a data-bind:click function on the primary viewmodel.  I used an example from here for some guidance, if anyone is interested(http://ericpanorel.net/2013/07/28/modal-dialog-for-hottowel-spa/)